# Exclude specific post from query

Tags: functions, theme-development, archives

In the category post archive, I want to display the last 10 posts and 1 featured post (featured post only on the first page).
I can choose a featured post that will be displayed first (user can select manually, its custom field is called ‘category_featured_post’ ). Now if the featured post is the same post that will be displayed in a list, It will be doubled (on featured position and on the list). I can hide this post on the list (if it is displayed on the first page where the featured post is displayed), but now there will be 9 posts on the list instead of 10. How can I display 10 posts in that case?

Custom field `category_featured_post` is on category, it is a Post Object that returns a single post ID.

Here is the code I have now:

```
<!-- DISPLAY FEATURED POST (ONLY ON FIRST PAGE) IN BIG TILE -->
<?php
    if ( !is_paged() ) :
        $post = get_post($featured_post);
        ?>
        <div class="tile">
            <h3><?php the_title(); ?></h3>
            <p><?php the_excerpt(); ?></p>
            <a href="<?php echo the_permalink(); ?>">Read post</a>
        </div>
        <?php
    endif;     
?>
```

```
<!-- DISPLAY POSTS IN LIST -->
<?php 
    if (have_posts()){
        while(have_posts()){
            the_post();

            // DON'T DISPLAY POST IF IT'S FEATURED
            if(get_the_ID() != $featured_post ){
                get_template_part('template-parts/post/content','archive');
            }
        }
    } 
?>
```

Comment: by the time `archive.php` is loaded the query has already ran, so changing its parameters will not change the number of posts because it's already fetched the posts, it's too late. Making it work this way would mean discarding the query and putting a new one in ( very bad for performance, will introduce lots of pagination issues ), or it would require time travelling into the past several micro-seconds. Additionally, post archives don't have an ID because they aren't posts/pages, they're archives

Comment: Instead of asking how to implement a proposed solution, ask how to solve your problem, what are you actually trying to do that requires this?

Comment: Thank for the answer, I edited the question.

Comment: you mentioned a custom field, but what is the custom field on? A category? `archive.php` covers all archives, date archives, tag archives etc etc, can you be more specific?

Comment: Custom field `category_featured_post` is on category, it is a Post Object that returns a single post ID.
I'm talking about posts archive.

Comment: Your last comment was contradictory, are you saying that this is a category archive that lists post and it's the category being viewed that has the field?

Comment: Ohh. This archive shows all posts from a specific category. Custom field `category_featured_post` is showed in all categories **if taxonomy = category**

Comment: Still not quite enough info, but… yes, you definitely want to modify the query — probably using pre_get_posts() — before it's run. The featured post isn't a 'sticky' post but a custom field, right? Is it a meta field *of that post*, or is it a separate field that elsewhere selects the post? If it's actually the post's meta field, you could just `orderby` the meta field first, then by your default ordering parameters. If you're using a post ID/slug instead, you'd probably need two queries, first using `post__in` to display the featured post(s), then using `post__not_in` to exclude them.

Comment: I use WP_query and use `'post__not_in' => array( $featured_id ),`  to exclude my featured post. You can put in ids you want to ignore. I just create a variable of `$id` or `$featured_id` before the query and set it as needed (array or single id, such as with `$id = $post->ID;`.

Comment: Thank you guys! `post__not_in` was what I was searching. I added it as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to *liquidRock* and *StudioAl* for solution!

**Exclude post from query:**

```
'post__not_in' => array( $featured_post_id )
```